# Substitution string highlighting in python triple quoted strings

Tags: python, notepad++

I m using python based Google App Engine for some project, and for writing Webapps, I have to use the string replacement functionality of python a lot using % operator.

I am using Notepad++ as my editor. I need some mechanism of highlighting substitution labels in """ triple-quoted strings, so that I can track them easily, if they are embedded in the string. For example, Below is a python triple quoted string, I'm using :

```
form    =   """
        <form   method="post"   >
            When is you Birthday?
            <br>
            <label> Day     <input  type="text" name="dd" value = "%(day)s">    </label>
            <label> Month   <input  type="text" name="mm" value = "%(month)s">  </label>
            <label> Year    <input  type="text" name="yy" value = "%(year)s">   </label>
            <div    style="color: red"> %(error)s </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <input  type="submit"   value="Submit"  >
        </form>
```

"""

Now, without proper highlighting of all the %()s patterns embedded in this string, it is pretty hard for me to judge. There are in total 4 such patterns embedded in this triple quoted string. (day, month, year and error)

If someone know a workaround of this problem, please let me know.

Regards
Vaid, Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

You will need to try and adjust your notepad++ Style/"Language" to fit your needs.

You can find the basics in langs.xml and style.xml, then there are also [User Defined Language Files](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=User_Defined_Language_Files) you can take a look at and possibly someone has already done it for another language.  I'm not sure if Notepad++ can do regex on fly like that to check for patterns matching %(*)s for eg, so you'll need to tinker some and google some.